# PHP: Get path after domain from current URL

Tags: php

I am a complete beginner to PHP, so please keep that in mind.

I am attempting to get JUST the path from the current URL, which is variable. For instance, if the current URL is `http://example.com/blog/2014/blogpost.html` then I would like to get `/blog/2014` or something very similar.

This is the PHP code I have so far:

```
$full_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$path_info =  parse_url($full_url,PHP_URL_PATH);
echo $path_info;
```

However, this does not work, and I can't seem to Google a suitable solution.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't work - what does it give?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `strrpos` to get the last index of `/` and pull the part of the URI before that with:

```
$req_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = substr($req_uri,0,strrpos($req_uri,'/'));
```

This will give you exactly what you wanted (`/blog/2014`)

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you "/blog/2014/" from your example:

```
$path_info = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

Comment: He want's just the path `/blog/2014` so you would need additional steps to remove the filename

Comment: This gives me no error messages and no output if I use `echo $path_info;`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
$url = "http://example.com/blog/2014/blogpost.html" ;
$parts = explode('/' , $url );
// then use any part of $parts by using $parts[i]
```